# RegEx not working properly for string replace

Tags: regex

I have 3 requirements. A string is coming from the ui and it will have:

```
1. A space in it.
2. A complete string together like <div><br></div>
3. Another complete string together like <span style='white-space:pre'> </span>
```

Now these 3 can be repetitive in a string. Example would be like:

```
<div><br></div> This is a <span style='white-space:pre'> </span>
<span style='white-space:pre'> </span> test <span style='white-space:pre'> </span>
```

I have a regex which goes like this:

```
function trimString(x) {
    return x.replace(/[ |<div><br><\/div>|
<span style='white\-space:pre'> <\/span>|<br>]+/g,' ');
    }
```

The final string that should be returned for this example is:

```
This is a test
```

This regex is seems to be taking care of first 2 requirements but fails at the last one. Any advice as to how i can make all of this work in 1 regex?

Comment: Square brackets `[ ]` are a regex character group. Try `()` instead?

Comment: You seems to be using JavaScript. Why not making use of the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is one big character class. You probably mean something like this

`/[ ]|<div><br><\/div>|<span[ ]style='white-space:pre'>[ ]<\/span>|<br>/`